# iOS token for push is not always in hexa format

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apns-php

Calling `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` returns non hexa tokens for some devices. Someone knows why ?

How can I deal with them to send my push notification from a web/server and a script written in PHP ?

The usual way that uses the pack PHP method will fails because it requires only hexa characters :

```
$msg = chr(0) . 
       pack('n', 32) . 
       pack('H*', **$token**) . 
       pack('n', strlen($payload)) . 
       $payload;
```

Comment: Did you convert Devicetoken into NSString from NSData? Please find php file in tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Comment: Yes I did. The tutorial is OK and I do get some tokens in hexa that I can use to push notifications. But for some devices, tokens are not hexa...